# Form submit not working when inside of a modal window. Bootstrap and Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am a bit stuck here, it does not work when inside of a modal but works if it is outside.

Here is my modal

```html
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">PLACE A VOUCHER ORDER</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="orders container">
    <h6>Please Complete the fields</h6>
    <form novalidate="novalidate" #orderForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>SENDER NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="senderName" #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.senderName" placeholder="Enter sender name" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>SENDER EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="senderEmail" #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.senderEmail" placeholder="Enter sender email" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>RECIPIENT NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipientName" #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.recipientName" placeholder="Enter recipient name" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>RECIPIENT EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipientEmail" #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.recipientEmail" placeholder="Enter recipient email" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>VOUCHER</label>
        <select name="voucher" class="form-control" #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.voucher" required>
          <option value="500">500 USD</option>
          <option value="1000">1000 USD</option>
          <option value="2500">2500 USD</option>
          <option value="5000">5000 USD</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>DEDICATION</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="dedication" #body="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.dedication" placeholder="Enter text" required></textarea>
      </div>

      <button [disabled]="orderForm.invalid" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Cross click')">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Here is the submit() on the ts file. The button is initially disabled when all the fields have not yet filled and in there is also my httppost method from the service ts.

```js
submit(): void {
    if(this.orderForm.invalid){
      return;
    }
    
    this.orderService.createOrder(this.model).subscribe(response => {
      alert('order successfully created!');

      console.log('Got response from API:', response);

    }, error => {
    }); 
  }
```

When I click submit nothing happens at all. It should show an alert when it is successfully submitted.

Comment: `<button [disabled]` ???

Comment: @mplungjan Oh that is a validation when all fields are not yet filled.

Comment: have you tried to make you submit button type as submit <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default save-btn">Submit</button>. Only a button of type submit submits the form.